# PhoneGap keep running on Android after onPause

Tags: android, cordova, background

I decided to test if phonegap WebView is live when app is in a background.

```
function test2(x){
    $('<div></div>', {text: x.cmd}).appendTo($('#list'));
}
$(function(){test2({cmd:"start"});});
function cb_pause(){test2({cmd:"pause"});}
function cb_resume(){   test2({cmd:"resume"});}
function tick(){test2({cmd:"timer" + timer});timer++;setTimeout(tick, 1000);}
document.addEventListener("pause", cb_pause, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", cb_resume, false);
tick();
```

It prints `pause` and `resume` on `onPause` and `onResume`.
and print `timer0`, `timer1`, etc every second.

It was printing even when I left app and started playing game.
I know I can and should stop timer in `onPause` but still. It looks wrong. I expected android will freeze WebView.

I know background thread will not stop if in background app until it is unloaded.

So question is: Is there way to freeze/suspend/unload webview on `onPause` and unfreeze/resume/load on `onResume`

When I say load I mean it should be in same state when user left app.

When I say freeze, I mean that my code to will pause even when it will continue to call `setTimeout`

I guess I expect Android to behave like iOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keepRunning PhoneGap/Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001439/keeprunning-phonegap-cordova)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am late with response. In phonegap there is `KeepRunning` param in `config.xml`

You must add following line to `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="false" />
```

It will call `pauseTimers()` and pause all WebViews. `pauseTimers()` is not hidden method and no reflection is needed.

Comment: I will reward you with bounty. Your answer is correct as it relates to phonegap

Comment: is this supposed to be '**IT** will call `pauseTimers`'? Because I'm looking for this feature specifically.

Comment: Not working. When i lock the screen audio still coming.

Answer (score 4):

This should help: [WebView threads never stop (WebViewCoreThread, CookieSyncManager, http[0-3])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040963/webview-threads-never-stop-webviewcorethread-cookiesyncmanager-http0-3)

Basically you have to use reflection to access the WebView's onPause/onResume methods to really make it pause and resume.