# cordova navigator.app.close() is keeping app in background

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to close my android app by calling cordova navigator.app.close(), app closes but still running in background and I can see it in app manager. 
I tried to solve this problem like it described there: [PhoneGap keep running on Android after onPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505369/phonegap-keep-running-on-android-after-onpause)
by inserting

```
<preference name="keepRunning" value="false" />
```

in config.xml, but it doesn't work for me.

Are there some other ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: You only close app and app will in background, still in task manager util system remove it (low memory).

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you running?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a function called `navigator.app.close()`. Did you mean to call `navigator.app.exitApp()`?

Here is a list of all of the available functions from `navigator.app`:

```
navigator.app.backHistory();
navigator.app.cancelLoadUrl();
navigator.app.clearCache();
navigator.app.clearHistory();
navigator.app.exitApp();
navigator.app.loadUrl(url, props);
navigator.app.overrideBackbutton(override);
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your Cordova version to 4.0+ and use navigator.app.exitApp();