# GPS collection app for multiple platforms

Tags: cordova

I have an application draft on my table, and I wanted to ask some questions. The application should be a simple app, that will collect GPS data (lat, lng) from the users device. I need this to be a multiple plaform solution, so far it's going to be iOS, Android and WP8.

My question is, if I develop the app with phonegap, will it work while my phone is locked? Am I going to be able to push the location requests when the app is running in the background?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cordova you can collect GPS data on various platforms.

In order to keep an app working while in background you need to include a custom own made plugin or use an existing one which keeps doing the job.

This is a [good plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) and works on all your desired 3 platforms. Give it a try.

also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584914/how-to-run-cordova-plugin-in-android-background-service).