# Is it possible to create a facebook messenger style notification via phonegap?

Tags: cordova, push-notification

Is it possible to create notifications similar to the Facebook Messenger notification on Android in phonegap? Its outside of the webview, so I don't think its possible but is an amazing feature.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i never tried this one and am not sure about images. you can display text notification with this plugin. try this cordova plugin,

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Thanks for this. Are these toast messages available when you minimize the app? Facebook messenger does this. But it is native.

Comment: You should add Background Service Plugin for getting notification during minimized mode. Check this link ->  https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService

Comment: and this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584914/how-to-run-cordova-plugin-in-android-background-service