# Meteor/Cordova: How to create a background service that runs when app is not open

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, service

Is there some way, using Meteor/Cordova, to instantiate a service that runs permanently in the background to do things like updating status bar notifications?

I understand that this can be done natively, on Android for example, by using IntentService and registering alarms, but I'd like a solution that does not involve writing native code.  I also think I understand that there exist plugins, like Background Service Plugin, that allow things to happen the the app is open but not in the foreground, but I want a service that runs even when the app is closed.

Comment: Related: [How to run cordova plugin in Android background service?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24584914/1366033)